# Is there any way to change rich:calendar holidays

Tags: css, richfaces

I need to change the holidays in rich:calendar component. By default component shows holidays as "Sunday" and "Saturday".

Below is the style class defined for highlighting the holidays.

```
.rich-calendar-holly
{
background-color: #FFEBDA;
}
```

I want this style to work on Friday and Saturday instead of Saturday and Sunday. Can someone advice me how can I achieve it richfaces ? Is there any attribute available to set the holidays ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additonal details: I want to change the weekends from Saturday, Sunday to Friday and Saturday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your custom CalendarDataModel so that it returns a certain css class for Friday and Saturday, such as

```
public class CalendarModelItem implements CalendarDataModelItem {
   //rest of code
   private String styleClass;
   public void setStyleClass(String styleClass) { this.styleClass = styleClass; }
   public String getStyleClass() { return styleClass; }
   //rest of code
}

public class CalendarModel implements CalendarDataModel {
    //rest of code
    public CalendarDataModelItem[] getData(Date[] dateArray) {
       CalendarDataModelItem[] modelItems = new CalendarModelItem[dateArray.length];
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       for (Date d : dateArray) {                
            c.setTime(d);
            CalendarModelItem modelItem = new CalendarModelItem();
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY || calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                modelItem.setStyleClass("weekend");
            } else {
                modelItem.setStyleClass("");
            }
            modelItems[i] = modelItem;
       }
       return modelItems;
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

define your custom css class and reset formatting by rich-calendar-holly

```
.rich-calendar-holly{
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
}
.weekend {
 background-color: #FFEBDA;
}
```

and then use this in the calendar component

```
<rich:calendar ... dataModel="#{calendarModel}" />
```